# How to remove all the associated in built events of a control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events

How to remove all the associated in built events of a control in WPF?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Could you give us a scenario?

Comment: i have a tab control, inside many checkboxes are their. If i click on one checkbox, operation takes long time so in that time if i click on any other checkbox, after the completion of first operation, the other click is raised. This is happening becoz events are getting queued up in the Dispatcher. So if i remove the eventhandlers at the start of operation and again add it after completion. May be my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to remove all events queued on the `Dispatcher`.  Even if there were, you wouldn't want to do so because it would break many WPF controls that rely on background events to update their data structures and UI.

However, there *is* an easy way to discard selected input events from the queue, such as keyboard, mouse and stylus events:

1. Create a "FlushInputQueue" method that registers an event handler with `InputManager.PreprocessInput`,  invokes a `DispatcherOperation` at Input priority, then removes the event handler.
2. When the `PreprocessInput` event fires, check the input message and set the `Handled` flag to true if you want to discard it.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
public void FlushInputQueue()
{
  PreProcessInputEvent handler = (obj, e) =>
  {
    if(ShouldFlushEvent(e.StagingItem.Input))
      e.StagingItem.Input.Handled = true;
  };
  InputManager.PreProcessInput += handler;
  Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() => {}));
  InputManager.PreProcessInput -= handler;
}

private bool ShouldFlushEvent(InputEventArgs e)
{
  // Example only:
  return e is MouseEventArgs || e is KeyboardEventArgs || e is StylusEventArgs;
}
```

The ShouldFlushEvent method should probably be customized for your particular scenario to avoid throwing out events that should be kept.

One last thought:  Have you considered doing your long-running operation on a background thread so the UI remains responsive?  Many times this is a better solution than locking the UI when an item is clicked on, and removes any reason for wanting to flush the queue.